# Como ler nome de objeto JSON contendo caractere especial?

Tags: javascript, json, objetos

Meu arquivo JSON:

[image: JSON nome de objeto com caracter trace]

**"locomotivas"** e **"vagoes"** consigo ler sem problemas, mas quando tento ler **"vagoes-cadastrar"** aí apresenta o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou seja, por causa do caracter " - ", está sendo interpretado como outro objeto! Como posso resolver isso? já pesquisei algumas coisas mas não encontrei nada ainda.

meu JS:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

desde já muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente:
`console.log(Object.keys(data['vagoes-cadastrar']).length);`

Além disso, é possivel, por exemplo, passarmos `palavras chaves` (do Javascript, como: `for, while, get, typeof`) para os nomes das chaves, como:

```js
obj["for"] = "Simon"; // Funciona bem
console.log(obj.for) //Incrivelmente, funciona também.
//Saída: Simon
```

> Nota: segundo o livro `You Don't Know JS`, ao chamarmos com essa sintaxe: `obj["for"]`, na verdade, estamos nos referindo ao acesso à "chave", enquanto que `obj.for`, referimos-nos à propriedade do objeto.
>
> "*A principal diferença entre as duas sintaxes é que o operador . requer um nome de propriedade Identifier compatível logo após ele, enquanto a sintaxe [".."] pode aceitar basicamente qualquer com string compatível com UTF-8/unicode como o nome da propriedade. Para referenciar uma propriedade de nome Super-Fun!, por exemplo, você teria que usar o sintaxe de acesso ["Super-Fun!"], pois Super-Fun! não é um nome de propriedade Identifier válido.*"

**REFERÊNCIA:**
1. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Objetos 
2. https://github.com/CristianoGil/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/portuguese-translation/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch3.md

Comment: maravilha! funcionou perfeitamente! muito obrigado Taffarel Xavier! abrç!

Comment: Não esqueça de votar como resposta principal. Agradeço, Ird.